# R shiny: ERROR: argument "metaHandler" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

1. I have a shiny app that runs fine on Windows (localhost), but when I upload it to a server, it  returns the error:

   > ```
   > ERROR: argument "metaHandler" is missing, with no default
   > ```
2. I know that the server is fine, because all the other apps in the directory are working correctly.
3. I have seen Joe Cheng's response to this [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/292), but I am not sure I understand what the resolution is.
4. My best guess as to what is causing the error is that there is a `fileInput` that is handled like so:

   shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 
   Data <- reactive({
     inFile <- input$file1

   if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL) 
     else {
     }
   }

Any ideas as to why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same error while formatting UI code, when i've put invalid line breaking in code.

Correct line breaking:

```
shinyUI(
pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Porównanie wartości błędu klasyfikacji"),
    sidebarPanel(
        ...
```

Incorrect:

```
shinyUI
(
    pageWithSidebar
    (
        headerPanel("Porównanie wartości błędu klasyfikacji"),
        sidebarPanel(
        ...
```